# Maui Blazor Hybrid .net7.0-android33.0 Cant sign package

Tags: android, maui, publish, android-keystore

I have a Maui Blazor Hybrid app, it runs on .net7.0 with target framework API 33 android 13. Since I have changed this I cant sign my android app. I can create my keystore file successfully, but as soon as I try and select the file to use, it disappears from the file upload box in the image below.

[Package Sign section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0zG6.png)

I have tried numerous times to re-create the keystore file, I checked the rights on the file, I have updated, uninstalled and reinstalled visual studio. Normal Android .net 7.0 work fine just on .net7.0-adroid33.0

Comment: *" Normal Android .net 7.0 work fine just on .net7.0-adroid33.0 "*  You mean if it's .net7.0-adroid33.0, the app will not work fine?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT yes as soos as I change the TargetFramework for android in the property settings to Android 13 API 33, it wont allow me to upload my keystore file when i try and do the package signing.

Comment: You mean you want this [effect](https://imgur.com/a/zK4ClxL)?

Comment: Hi everyone, I got another way to sign which resolved the issue, I unchecked the sign package in the Android options section, then once the archive is created I click on distribute and can then successfully create the signature and signage of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to your comment, as an answer:

> I unchecked the sign package in the Android options section, then once
> the archive is created I click on distribute and can then successfully
> create the signature and signage of the package.